# array list reference issue in android

Tags: android, arraylist

I have two arrayList of objects. I want to make them seperate. I copied content from one array list to another. But when i change content of one array list. Change occurs in both. Please help. I try everything clone,set methods. But nothing worked

Comment: Post your code. Possibly you're not aware of the fact that the arraylist holds the object references not the objects itself.

Comment: How can i make separate arryList. I have some data in one list that i dont want to edited. I want to edit the data of second list

Comment: As Jitsu answered . Just make sure the object you are storing in list is implementing the Cloneable interface. http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=344

Comment: Do accept Jitsu answer then. Cheers

Comment: I accepted that answer. Actually I was doing mistake in the clonable interface. Your link helped me to sort out my issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is called **deep copy** and actually inserts new object into the new list. Make sure clone() works for you objects by default, or is overriden **properly**:

```
// Old list declaration
ArrayList<Object> mOldList = new ArrayList<Object>)();

// New List declaration
ArrayList<Object> mNewList = new ArrayList<Object>();

for(Object o : mOldList) {
    // Iterate over the old list and clone the elements into the new list
    mNewList.add(o.clone());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you want to copy arrayList to other you should clone it:

(It works fine with collections)

```
ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> a = b.clone();
```

or new it by first array like this:

(copy-constructors way,better way)

```
ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList(a);
```

Comment: Wrong. This will still copy the references.

Comment: @user2050075 I surely say this ways work but in some situation second way work